# Plotting tendency line in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, overlap

I want to plot a tendency line on top of a data plot.  This must be simple but I have not been able to figure out how to get to it.

Let us say I have the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 1)), columns=list('A'))
sns.lineplot(data=df)

ax.set(xlabel="Index",
       ylabel="Variable",
       title="Sample")

plt.show()
```

The resulting plot is:

[image]

What I would like to add is a tendency line. Something like the red line in the following:

[image]

I thank you for any feedback.

Comment: Would a sliding average be sufficient for your needs?

Comment: hmmm I guess it would. I'll check how to do that. Thanks @Guimoute for the idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this using Rolling Average:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data  = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 1))

df["rolling_avg"] = df.A.rolling(7).mean().shift(-3)

sns.lineplot(data=df)

plt.show()
```

[image]

You could also do a Regression plot to analyse how data can be interpolated using:

```
ax = sns.regplot(x=df.index, y="A", 
                 data=df,
                 scatter_kws={"s": 10},
                 order=10, 
                 ci=None)
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent @RafaelAguilar this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

A moving average is one method (my first thought, and already suggested).

Another method is to use a polynomial fit. Since you had 100 points in your original data, I picked a 10th order fit (square root of data length) in the example below. With some modification of your original code:

```
idx = [i for i in range(100)]
rnd = np.random.randint(0,100,size=100)
ser = pd.Series(rnd, idx)

fit = np.polyfit(idx, rnd, 10)
pf = np.poly1d(fit)

plt.plot(idx, rnd, 'b', idx, pf(idx), 'r')
```

This code provides a plot like this:

[image: random data with polynomial fit]

Comment: Polynomial fits are evil (look at what you have at the left boundary).

Comment: Thank you @FrontRanger for the idea. It is very much appreciated